# xml schema with unique id

Tags: xml, xsd

Hello i have to do xsd file for univeristy example. My xsd file should have information about departments. Every department should have unique id xs:ID and then name and optional number of addreses. On department there are employees that should have also unique id of specific department. Every employe have name, surname mandatory, optional title and three categories. Everyone should 've addres at least one in specific sequence. On university there is also list of subjects, where each subject has unique id, description and number of students. For each subject it should be defined employed xs:IDREF. I Have something like this:
How add this IDREF to subjects and i have issue when im trying to open this in xsd diagram. I get information that attribiute element is unkown and node is unkown. What is wrong here and how to fix this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    
    <xs:element name="university">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="department" >
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="id_department"><xs:attribute name="id_department"
                                        type="xs:ID"
                                        use="required"/></xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="name"
                                    type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="address"
                                    type="xs:string"
                                    maxOccurs="unbounded"  ></xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="employee" >
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="id_employee"
                                                type="xs:ID"
                                                minOccurs="1">
                                            <xs:attribute name="id_employee"
                                                    type="xs:ID"
                                                    use="required"/>
                                        </xs:element>
                                        <xs:element name="name"
                                                type="xs:string"
                                                minOccurs="1"></xs:element>
                                        <xs:element name="surname"
                                                type="xs:string"
                                                minOccurs="1"></xs:element>
                                        <xs:element name="title"
                                                type="xs:string"
                                                minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
                                        <xs:element name="category"
                                                type="xs:string">
                                            <xs:simpleType>
                                                <xs:restriction base="string">
                                                    <xs:enumeration value="science"></xs:enumeration>
                                                    <xs:enumeration value="administration"></xs:enumeration>
                                                    <xs:enumeration value="technical"></xs:enumeration>
                                                </xs:restriction>
                                            </xs:simpleType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                        <xs:element name="address" minOccurs="1">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:sequence>
                                                    <xs:element name="street"></xs:element>
                                                    <xs:element name="number"></xs:element>
                                                    <xs:element name="zip_code"></xs:element>
                                                    <xs:element name="city"></xs:element>
                                                </xs:sequence>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="subject">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="id_subject"
                                                type="xs:string"> <xs:attribute name="id_subject"
                                                    type="xs:ID"
                                                    use="required"/></xs:element>
                                        <xs:element name="name"
                                                type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                        <xs:element name="description"
                                                type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                        <xs:element name="students_count"
                                                type="xs:int"><xs:minInclusive value="6"/>
                                            <xs:maxInclusive value="400"/>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: "I get information that attribiute element is unkown and node is unkown. " Please give the actual error message. It might seem rather technical to you, but for those of us familiar with the technology, it's going to be much more helpful than your paraphrase.

Answer (score 0):

`xs:attribute` can't appear as a child of `xs:element`. You need to define an `xs:complexType` for the element, and the attribute can be defined as part of the complexType.